# Cucumber step definition local variables being re-used?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have been doing quite some research on cucumber step definitions local variables but I can't find anywhere how cucumber handles local variables and I am encountering some weird behavior with them, as if they were not local variables. The variables are using the same memory address and maintaining state, for example:

```
Then(/^the password is "(.?*)"$/) do |password|
  puts password
  puts password.object_id
  password.concat("s")
end
```

The inputs for the variable **password** would be the same - password1234, password1234, password1234 but the output would be:

```
password1234
32607252

password1234
32607240

password1234s
32607252

password1234ss
32607252

password1234s
32607240
```

Note how object address -32607252- is being reused, I ran this with multiple scenario examples and a lot of times the object address would be duplicate in different test case scenarios and the concatenation of the "s" would show up even though **password** is supposed to be a local variable.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a cucumber bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I e-mailed the cucumber developer team and they have opened an issue to discuss this

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/760